# Function "hiding" and OnSize

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2017, member-hiding

I really don't get this. Take the [`OnSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#onsize) function:

```
afx_msg void OnSize(
    UINT nType,  
    int cx,  
    int cy);
```

So, it is not virtual. So we make our own method using ClassWizard in our derived class. Eg:

```
void CCreateReportDlg::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CResizingDialog::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    if (m_Grid.GetSafeHwnd() != nullptr)
        m_Grid.ExpandColumnsToFit();
}
```

You run that through the latest code analysis and it throws a warning about hiding a non-virtual function. But we **are** calling the **base** class function. This is standard MFC boiler plate code (is that the right terminology?).

So it is not hidden. Surely this warning should only flag if the base class implementation is not called?

Comment: As far as the compiler knows, any other member function can call OnSize(). So, it does hide the base class function.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code. It looks like VS 2017 Code Analysis has a lot of useless warnings likes this one. You have to ignore it again.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson Yes, but the point is this function *is* calling the base function so  it is *not* actually a problem and a completely unrequired warning to be raised.

Comment: For the warning it is not relevant whether you call the base function or not. The warning is because someone may call `OnSize()` through a pointer of a base class, but in this case your own function won't run, as it just hides the base function instead of overriding it. Granted, the warning is still useless because this is not how MFC message maps work, but the compiler doesn't know.

Comment: @zett42 `CWnd::OnSize` is `protected`, it needs more effort to miss-use it. By the way, it's not a compiler warning, it's *"Code Analysis"* warning which appears for all `CWnd` overrides.